# Command Line curl to PHP cURL issues (500 server error)

Tags: php, curl, command-line

I am connecting to an API with multipart/form-data, if I send the request via curl on the command line I have no issues, but when sending it with PHP cURL I get an internal server 500 error.

The command line is

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "X-DevKey: XXX" -H "X-AccessToken: XXX" -F "data=@file.json; type=application/json" -X POST https://api.site.com/v1/Items -i -v
```

Which, give me the following response

```
> POST /v1/Items HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5
> Host: api.site.com
> Accept: */*
> X-DevKey: XXX
> X-AccessToken: XXX
> Content-Length: 1008
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------58bf5d52327e
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< Set-Cookie: sto-id=XXX; Expires=Fri, 16-May-2025 15:32:27 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sto-id=XXX; Expires=Fri, 16-May-2025 15:32:27 GMT; Path=/

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
Expires: -1
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:32:28 GMT
Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:32:28 GMT
< Content-Length: 220
Content-Length: 220
< Set-Cookie: sto-id=XXX; Expires=Fri, 16-May-2025 15:32:28 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sto-id=XXX; Expires=Fri, 16-May-2025 15:32:28 GMT; Path=/

< 
* Connection #0 to host api.site.com left intact
{"userMessage":"Item listed with itemID: 484495200","developerMessage":"Item listed with itemID: 484495200","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://api.site.com/v1/items/484495200","verb":"GET","title":"484495200"}]}* Closing connection #0
## Heading ##* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

My current PHP function looks like this

```
function create_listing($buynow, $startingBid, $category, $description, $picture, $sku, $title)
{
$url = "https://api.site.com/v1/Items";
$token = get_access_token();
$headers = array(
    "X-DevKey: XXX",
    "X-AccessToken: $token",
    "Expect: 100-continue",
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; Boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryR7f7XrG1vJhOfHzu"
);
$data = array(
    "AutoRelist" => 1,
    "AutoRelistFixedCount" => 0,
    "BuyNowPrice" => 9.99,
    "CategoryID" => 2325,
    "Condition" => 1,
    "CountryCode" => 'US',
    "Description" => $description,
    "InspectionPeriod" => 1,
    //"FixedPrice" => $fixedprice,
    "IsFFLRequired" => true,
    "ListingDuration" => 1,
    "PaymentMethods" => array(
        "Check" => false,
        "VisaMastercard" => true,
        "COD" => false,
        "Escrow" => false,
        "Amex" => false,
        "PayPal" => false,
        "Discover" => true,
        "SeeItemDesc" => true,
        "CertifiedCheck" => true,
        "USPSMoneyOrder" => true,
        "MoneyOrder" => false
    ),
    "PostalCode" => '85388',
    "Quantity" => 1,
    //"ReservePrice" => $reserve,
    "SalesTaxes" => array(
        array(
            "State" => 'AZ',
            "TaxRate" => 8.5
        )
    ),
    //"SerialNumber" => $serial,
    "ShippingClassCosts" => array(
        "Ground" => 25.00,
        "Priority" => 25.00
    ),
    "ShippingClassesSupported" => array(
        "Overnight" => false,
        "TwoDay" => false,
        "ThreeDay" => false,
        "Ground" => true,
        "FirstClass" => false,
        "Priority" => true,
        "Other" => false
    ),
    //"ShippingProfileID" => $shippingProfile,
    "SKU" => $sku,
    "StartingBid" => 0.99,
    "Title" => $title,
    //"UPC" => $upc,
    //"Weight" => $weight,
    //"WeightUnit" => 1,
    "WhoPaysForShipping" => 8,
    //"ItemPremiumFeatures" => array(
    //    
    //),
    "WillShipInternational" => false
);
$boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundaryR7f7XrG1vJhOfHzu';
$request = "$boundary\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\n";
$request .= json_encode($data) . "\n$boundary--";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);                                                                   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === FALSE) {
printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
       htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
}
rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if (!$result) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

return $result;

}
```

But I get the following response:

```
> POST /v1/Items HTTP/1.1
Host: api.site.com
Accept: */*
Cookie: sto-id=JKHHNMED
X-DevKey: XXX
X-AccessToken: XXX
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; Boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryR7f7XrG1vJhOfHzu
Content-Length: 939

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 17:11:40 GMT
< Content-Length: 219
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
```

Any help as to why I'm getting the 500 error would be greatly appreciated.